# Special student Harvard in Mathematics

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states

I am a master student in Mathematics. I got a scholarship that would pay me a 1-year stay (including housing etc.) at Harvard University. All I need to do, is to apply for admission as a Special student at the Graduate School of Arts and Sciences (and be admitted of course).

Searching through the internet, some people indicated that admission as a special student is a: if you pay, you are in-system. Is this true? Or is admission as competitive as the one for regular students in the PhD programms?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Unfortunately, you really need to ask people at Harvard about this, rather than strangers on the internet who are not in a position to tell you how this particular program at Harvard works.

Comment: You need someone from Harvard to write a letter for you or you must be really good. This program was very selective: the students basically get the same rights, including voting and have their names engraved, as other students.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check on the rules at Harvard, but in general, "special student" generally means that a student is allowed to take courses but not to get a degree from the university.  The phrase "non-degree seeking student" is also sometimes used for this status.

It can be easier to be admitted as a special student than as a regular student, but it's also typically hard (as hard as getting admitted as a regular student) to switch from "special" status to regular degree seeking status.